# Is there any well-known reason for this Django issue?

Tags: django

I created a django (1.8+) project some time ago, and it's weird that it works well with runserver, but it's not working with gunicorn (requests never end, nothing is received using `curl` or any browser to test my server). The funny fact is that it worked until recently (I'm in an AWS/AmazonLinux server; never changed the server image).

Since this timeout really annoyed me (and still does) I checked the project, opened a python interactive interpreter inside my virtualenv, and tried:

```
from my_project.wsgi import application
```

inside the appropiate folder (so this statement does not raise `ImportError`). But that single line took a lot (at least 10 seconds) to execute.

I think that is the reason why is gunicorn not working.

Is there any well-known reason this could happen? How can I debug further?

**Edit** My gunicorn command: `gunicorn trescloud_landing.wsgi:application --daemon --bind=127.0.0.1:8888 --pid=/opt/webapps/pid/landing-pages.pid --access-logfile=/opt/webapps/log/landing-pages.access.log --error-logfile=/opt/webapps/log/landing-pages.error.log`

**Edit 2** Changed --timeout=600 (yes, 10 minutes) and gunicorn worked. But it is still troublesome to me that the server has a somehow low wsgi bootstrap

Comment: `python -v` may give some useful hints

Comment: are you using `nginx` for reversed proxy?

Comment: It is irrelevant. The problem even arose by using `curl` directly to the server (no proxy between). I have nginx but it is not bringing any trouble at all (I thought that at first instance)